# set toogle button to ON state when activity starts android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using a toogle button to start and stop functioning an object it works very fine, all i need to do is set the toogle state as ON when the activity starts.

Here is my code:

```
private void animationFart() {
    ImageView imageanimate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageanimate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageanimate.getDrawable();
    if (animation.isRunning()) {
        animation.stop();
    }
    animation.start();
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        // Enable vibrate
        animationFart();
    } 
    else {
        // Disable vibrate
        if (animation.isRunning()) {
            animation.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually do this in xml.

Comment: @Aleem Ahmed did you checked?

Answer (score 1):

In your `onCreate()` of `Activity` put

```
    start= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switch1);       
    start.toggle();
     // Enable vibrate
    animationFart(); // Start the Animation as Activity starts
```

---

```
toggle()
```

> Change the checked state of the view to the inverse of its current
>   state

By default ToggleButton will be in off state .So , you just toggle it .

Or you can use `toggleButton.setChecked(true);`

Comment: Didnt get you, where should i put this line?

Comment: The toogle button appears on when the application starts but it is not Playing the animation, the animation is stoped.

Comment: You are calling animatiom method in the onClick & if the ToggleButton is ON only. When you start the Activity it will be ON & will be off when you click it.Then how can you start the Animation.Do some changes logically.

Comment: and any suggestions for that?

Comment: Whats your expected output ? How ToggleButton should behave ?

Comment: It should be ON, and the animation should be playing when the activity starts. Upon pressing off than it should be off and the animation should be  off too. It is working fine except on start the animation is not playing whereas the button shows ON. When i press it to make it off and after that when its pressed back on the animation plays.

Comment: Then why don't you start the Animation in onCreate() itself.See the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75362/discussion-between-aleem-ahmed-and-don-chakkappan).

Answer (score 0):

Use this after activity starts

```
toggleButton.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: The toogle button appears on when the application starts but it is not Playing the animation, the animation is stoped.